# Why are these two lists equal, but act different when operated on?

Tags: python

```
height = 5
empty_pyramid = [['*'] * (height * 2)] * height



empty_pyramid2 = [['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'], ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
                ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'], ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'],
                ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*']]

if empty_pyramid == empty_pyramid2:
    print(True)
```

Both print True, but when put through a `for` loop the operations done on each iteration through `empty_pyramid2` will only affect the current element 
(ie: `['*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*']`)

while each operation done on `empty_pyramid`'s current element is applied to the other elements as well.

Comment: What operation are you doing and what are the results in question?

Comment: i'm looping through each element and replacing some '*' with numbers, building a triangle essentially. For example, the first layer replacing the first and last asterisk. The second layer replacing the first 2 and last 2 asterisk. But the for loop is applying changes to every element in empty_pyramid each time, so the end result is a pyramid consisting of all layers identical to what should be only the last layer (all numbers).

Comment: Got it - the linked answer in the closed message explains the behavior.